# Kubernetes deployments in IBM Cloud fails for me

Tags: docker, deployment, kubernetes, ibm-cloud

I try and deploy an app in a kubernetes cluster following these instructions

https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/containers?topic=containers-cs_apps_tutorial#cs_apps_tutorial

Then I make a build following the instructions with ibmcloud cr build -t registry..bluemix.net//hello-world:1 .

Output looks good except a securitywarning

SECURITY WARNING: You are building a Docker image from Windows against a non-Windows Docker host. All files and directories added to build context will have '-rwxr-xr-x' permissions. It is recommended to double check and reset permissions for sensitive files and directories.

But as this was just a test I did not worry.

At the next stage running this command following instructions

kubectl run hello-world-deployment --image=registry..bluemix.net//hello-world:1

I get the following error
error: failed to discover supported resources: Get http://localhost:8080/apis/apps/v1?timeout=32s: dial tcp [::1]:8080: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

As you see in the message it looks like it is trying to do something to my local PC rather than the IBMCloud. What have I missed to do?

Comment: As you said - it's trying to deploy to kube running on your local machine.  That usually means that the KUBECONFIG environment variable isn't set.  Run `ibmcloud ks cluster-config CLUSTERNAME` and that should give you a command back (on windows, it'll be something like "SET KUBECONFIG=....").  Run that command, and then kubectl will be able to target your cloud cluster.

Comment: Thanks that solved it for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @N Fritze mentioned in the comment, in order to organize access to Kubernetes cluster you might require to set `KUBECONFIG` environment variable which holds a list of `kubeconfig` files needed to provide sufficient information about authentication method in API server.

Find more information about managing Kubernetes Service in official IBM Cloud [documentation](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/containers/cs_cli_install.html#cs_cli_install). As issue has been already solved, answer composed for any further contributors research.